# Generate Array of Objects using Lodash from Redux Reducer in Selector for FlatList

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash, reselect, react-native-flatlist

if you don't know React etc, read here. Below is the same question but more related to React etc:

I have severel Objects containing one sort of data:
Prices:

```
'btc-usd' : 2640, 'ltc-usd': 40, ...
```

Amount of Crypto:

```
'btc-usd': 2.533, 'ltc-usd': 10.42, ...
```

How can I take these Objects and create an Array of Objects like:

```
[ { name: 'Bitcoin', amount: 2.533, value: 2640, id: 'btc-usd' },
 { name: 'Litecoin', amount: 10.42, value: 40, id: 'ltc-usd' }, ...
]
```

---

For React Programmers:

To use the new FlatList Component in React you need to provide an Array of Objects

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

I use several reducers that store different sorts of cryptocurrency data.
Reducer1 stores prices:

```
'btc-usd' : 2640,'ltc-usd': 40`
```

Reducer2 stores the amount of crypto you have:

```
'btc-usd': 2.533,'ltc-usd': 10.42
```

My goal is to iterate through these values and create an array of Objects like

```
[ { name: 'Bitcoin', amount: 2.533, value: 2640, id: 'btc-usd' },
 { name: 'Litecoin', amount: 10.42, value: 40, id: 'ltc-usd' }, ...
]
```

So far, I think the proper way is to do it in a Selector with reselect. The part missing is the lodash Part in the createSelector.
Surprisingly I didn't find anything combining lodash and FlatList on the internet. 
Thanks a lot for helping.

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import _ from 'lodash';

export const selectRate = (state) => state.rate;
export const selectCryptoBalance = (state) => state.cryptoBalance;


export const createCoinArray = createSelector(
  selectRate, selectCryptoBalance,
  (rate, cryptoBalance) => {
     const coinArray = []; //better load array from state?

//IMPROVEMENT NEEDED HERE
     _.forIn(selectRate, () => {
        coinArray.push(_.assign({ [selectRate.id]: 0 }, cryptoBalance));
        console.log('coinArray in loop ', coinArray);
     });
     return coinArray;
  }
);
```

---

Solution worked! more solutions here [Generate Array of Objects of different Objects Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784387/generate-array-of-objects-of-different-objects-javascript)
Thanks for helping! A lot of React users will appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following objects

```
prices = {'btc-usd' : 2640,'ltc-usd': 40, ... }
rates = {'btc-usd': 2.533,'ltc-usd': 10.42, ...}
names = {'btc-usd': 'Bitcoin' ...}
```

You could do

```
_.map(prices,(value,id) => ({name:names[id], amount:rates[id], value,id}))
```