# Generate Array of Objects of different Objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I have severel Objects containing one sort of data:
Prices:

```
'btc-usd' : 2640, 'ltc-usd': 40, ...
```

Amount of Crypto:

```
'btc-usd': 2.533, 'ltc-usd': 10.42, ...
```

How can I take these Objects and create an Array of Objects like:

```
[ { name: 'Bitcoin', amount: 2.533, value: 2640, id: 'btc-usd' },
 { name: 'Litecoin', amount: 10.42, value: 40, id: 'ltc-usd' }, ...
]
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the keys of one of the objects to produce a new array of objects. You just have to make sure, that the key is in every of these objects.

```
const names = {
    'btc-usd' : 'Bitcoin', 
    'ltc-usd': 'Litecoin', 
    ...
}

const prices = {
    'btc-usd' : 2640, 
    'ltc-usd': 40, 
    ...
}

const amounts = {
    'btc-usd': 2.533, 
    'ltc-usd': 10.42, 
    ...
}

const cryptos = Object.keys(names).map((key, index) => ({
    name: names[key],
    amount: amounts[key] , 
    value: prices[key]},
    id: key
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash map (e.g. *'btc-usd' => {name:"Bitcoin",...}*) to create new objects. This hashmap can be easily converted to an array.

```
var input={
  value:{'btc-usd' : 2640, 'ltc-usd': 40},
  amount:{'btc-usd': 2.533, 'ltc-usd': 10.42},
  name:{"btc-usd":"Bitcoin","ltc-usd":"Litecoin"}
};

var hash={};
for(key in input){
   var values=input[key];
   for(id in values){
      if(!hash[id]) hash[id]={id:id};
      hash[id][key]=values[id];
    }
}

var output=Object.values(hash);
```

http://jsbin.com/fadapafaca/edit?console

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized function, `add`, that accepts a field name and an object of values and maps them into a `result` object which can then be mapped into an array.

```js
const amounts = {btc: 123.45, eth: 123.45};
const names = {btc: 'Bitcoin', eth: 'Etherium'};

const result = {};

const add = (field, values) => {
  Object.keys(values).forEach(key => {
    // lazy initialize each object in the resultset
    if (!result[key]) {
      result[key] = {id: key};
    }

    // insert the data into the field for the key
    result[key][field] = values[key];
  });
}

add('amount', amounts);
add('name', names);

// converts the object of results to an array and logs it
console.log(Object.keys(result).map(key => result[key]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const prices = {
  'btc-usd' : 2640,
  'ltc-usd': 40
};

const amounts = {
  'btc-usd': 2.533,
  'ltc-usd': 10.42
};
```

First, create a dictionary of what each abbreviation stands for.

```
const dictionary = {
  'btc': 'Bitcoin',
  'ltc': 'Litecoin'
};
```

Then, populate an empty array with objects containing the relevant information. In each of these objects, the name would correspond to the relevant key within the `dictionary` object. At the same time, the amount and value would correspond to the relevant key within the `amounts` and `prices` objects respectively. Finally, the `Id` would correspond to the `key` itself.

```
const money = [];

for(let coin in prices) {
  money.push({
    name: dictionary[coin.substr(0, coin.indexOf('-'))],
    amount: amounts[coin],
    value: prices[coin],
    id: coin
  });
}

console.log(money);
```